# Iphone app issue

Tags: iphone, ios10

This question is similar to someone elses. But my phone says untrusted app developer. I click cancel, and by the way I am using ios10, and I go to settings to where there should be trust. but there isn't. it is replaced by verify apps. I click verify apps, and the apps  still come up unverified. one app I used was tutuapp.vip, what should I do so I can get back on my apps?
May sound like a child but I am 14, and play games and I'm taking an early start of creating one for a future job of mine.

Comment: I just need to know what to do, I cant delete the apps and regain them because its not letting me download tutuapp.vip again

Comment: please answer when you can

Answer (score 0):

Apple has this thing where if you download a game or an app from an untrusted developer, they have the option to resign the app. This means that apple is forcing you to not to open the application. Apple usually only resigns apps that are illegal (e.g. Getting paid apps for free, emulators, etc.)This means that you cannot get your data back, and you are forced to either start over, or to legally download the apps on apples app store.

Sorry, there is no way to get your apps back.